# fnGetPosition is not a function-datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, html-table, jeditable

Friends ,I am trying to update my datatable as soon as i make an edit using jeditable.So that the new data get updated in the datatable and whenever i search for it ,it should be visible in the search result .But presently everything is working fine but the only problem is that whenever i edit something and search for the new edited value then the search result shows-no result found.
In order to overcome this i used the following code but now it gives me error saying -"fnGetPosition is not a function".Here is the code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table1 = $('#tasksheet').DataTable();
   table1.$('.edit_areaD<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>').editable('savetask.php', {
          id: 'element_id',
          name: 'dhanraj',
          indicator : 'Saving...',
          placeholder: "",
         onblur:'submit',
          cssclass: 'textheight',
         tooltip   : 'click to edit...',
  "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = table1.fnGetPosition( this );
            table1.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": table1.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        },
     });
});
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well ,even i thought that it should be `.dataTable()` instead of `.DataTable()` .But when i change it to `.dataTable()` it says `table1.search ` is not a function.@JaromandaX

Comment: we.. then suggest me a better way of doing that..because as far as now ..i got only this..@JaromandaX

Comment: yes i am getting fnGetPostion is not a function@JaromandaX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126881/discussion-between-payal-suthar-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: Its solved
i used a bit of different way
as for search it requires .DataTable()
and for fnGetPosition it requires .datatable()
so i reinitialized it for search
thanks any ways @JaromandaX

Answer (score 3):

Well after a long struggle and with the help of JaromandaX.Here is the answer.
change this-

```
 var table1 = $('#tasksheet').DataTable();
```

to this-

```
 var table1 = $('#tasksheet').dataTable();
```

Answer (score 3):

For a better explanation about this:

The difference using `DataTable()` VS Using `datatable()`:

> The difference between the two is that the first will return a jQuery
>   object, while the second returns a DataTables API instance.

Following https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert:

To get the index via `datatable()` you'll need to use the `fnGetPosition` function.

To get the same via `DataTable()` you'll need to use `row().index()`: 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()